Would the code in lambda run within the same transaction？
BizService class, marked as transactional
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void rollbackCredit(List<Order> orderList) {
        // omitted biz code
    }

TransactionalHelper and Operation class:
public class TransactionalHelper {

    @Transactional(
        rollbackFor = {Exception.class}
    )
    public void transactionOperation(final Operation operation) {
        operation.execute();
    }

}


public interface Operation {
    void execute();
}

Now, I write the code as below. Would the code in lambda run in the same transaction?
Or method orderLogRepository.batchInsertSelective(logList) throw Exception,the data changing in  method bizService.rollbackCredit(orderList) and orderRepository.batchUpdateOptional(orderList, "orderStatusCode")  would be persisted in the database?
transactionalHelper.transactionOperation(() -> {
    // call service method with @Transactional
    bizService.rollbackCredit(orderList);
    // db operation
    orderRepository.batchUpdateOptional(orderList, "orderStatusCode");
    // db operation
    orderLogRepository.batchInsertSelective(logList);
});


It will run in the same TX. By default Spring will start a transaction on the first @Transactional and propagate it through any others, unless the nested @Transactional propagation is set to something like Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.

Answered by @Augusto in the comments:
It will run in the same transaction. By default Spring will start a transaction on the first @Transactional and propagate it through any others, unless the nested @Transactional propagation is set to something like Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.
Additional info by myself:
You could just mark your Service with @Transactional and execute the three method calls in it. Without TransactionHelper and callbacks.
Are you sure you want only to rollbackFor = Exception.class and not for RuntimeExceptions too?

Yes, in my case rollback for Exception.class. I know If no custom rollback rules are configured in this annotation, the transaction will roll back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions. TransactionalHelper is used to simplify the code instead of creating a new service every time.

Ok, just wanted to be sure! :)
